# PHP How to handle $_GET varibles

Tags: php, arrays

I'm learning PHP. Making a songbook site were users can find song lyrics and other stuff. Here I have huge no. of songs and I want to list them in separate alphabetic pages.

```
$songbook = array( 

"a" => array( 
"153" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
"154" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
),

"b" => array( 
"155" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
"156" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
),

"c" => array( 
"157" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
"158" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
),);
```

Table of songs.

```
<table class="list">
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($songbook as $song => $lyric) { ?>

<tr><td class="title"><a href="publicsong.php?id=<?php echo $song; ?>"><?php echo $lyric["title"]; ?></a></td>
<td class="artist"><?php echo $lyric["artist"]; ?></td>
<td class="category"><?php echo $lyric["tags"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

```
publicsong.php?id=153

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $songbook = strip_bad_chars( $_GET['id'] );
        $song = $songbook[$songbook];
    }
```

Everything works fine if i remove alphabet arrays `"a" => array( "b" => array( "c" => array(` But I want this `publicsearch.php?browse=a` page which displays the list of songs alphabetically.

I don't know how to handle multidimensional arrays.

This http://mysongbook.ca/ site may help you to understand better. Please go to the link. There at the left side there is a navigation menu (alphabets A B C D E F G..) Navigated to a list of artists songs. That list directed to id content and so on page. I want to use this sites method in my site. Please help. I'm newbie and I was stuck. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean about handling? What do you wanna do?

Comment: look at you var names `$songbook` cant be two things

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian I dont know how to set up logic to handle that a => array( list in a separate page. Please visit http://mysongbook.ca/ if you not get my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to have two arrays. One array contains all the song details, indexed by song ID. The second array would group them alphabetically:

```
$allSongs = array(
    "153" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
    "154" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
    "155" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
    "156" => array( "title" => "", "content" => "", "tags" => "",),
    ...
);
$alphaSongs = array(
    'a' => array(153, 154);
    'b' => array(155, 156);
    ...
);
```

Then you can just use `$allSongs[$_GET['id']]` to find the song given an ID.

You could also have other arrays like `$authorSongs` and `$genreSongs`.

If you were doing this for real, you would probably use a database instead of arrays.